# How to have response of an event generated from one class in another class?

Tags: java, jbutton, event-listener

I have a class extending JFrame which contains group of radioButtons and a submit button. When a user clicks one of them, a new frame opens and the submit button in the previous one is disabled. Now if this new frame is closed, I need that the submit button becomes enabled again. How to do it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have have the parent JFrame implement [WindowListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html) and register it with the child JFrame. When the child JFrame closes it will call the windowClosed() method of the Windowlistener.

As an example look at [this](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/326.html).

**UPDATE:**

Say your new frame is called `JFrame newFrame` and the button you want to enable is called `JRButton button` when you build the newFrame you would do something like this, before making the frame visible:

```
  newFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
            button.setEnabled(true);
        }            
    });
```

This will fire when ever the new frame is closed.

Comment: @jigsawmnc Yes, WindowAdapter in the example link implements all the methods in WindowListner. So you simply extend it and implment the one you actually want to do something with.

Comment: @jigsawmnc added an example for you, does that make more since?

Comment: As you suggested,I made the parent jframe implement windowListener and registered it as the listener for all events in the child frame. The only difference was that I needed to override windowClosing method of windowListener (with the command to enable the Button) to get things working. Otherwise your answer was perfect and I would like to thank you for clearing my concepts in eventhandling

Comment: @jigsawmnc No probelm, glad I could help. That is what SO is all about, getting help when you need it, and helping when others do.